# GFCI Suddenly Tripping

Tags: kitchens, gfci

I have 4 GFCI plugs on the kitchen wall that have been there for a few years. Late afternoon yesterday, all 4 tripped. I kept resetting them and they kept tripping. 2 are on 1 breaker and 2 on another. I replaced 1 late last evening and all was well today. About the same time it happened again. The wall faces west and we are having record heat. The afternoon sun shines on the wall. Can that be causing the problem?

Comment: NUMBER 1 TURN OFF CAPS! next you only need 1 gfci at the first outlet for each circuit, the second GFCI creates the possibility of nuncence trips even when everything is good. Last question is this a multi wire branch circuit, this was a common way to wire outlets of 2 circuits in the past with 1 more wire than a single circuit a big savings over pulling 2 cables. I have found newer GFCI'S to have more trips so we need to understand the wiring first to point you to the best solution

Comment: What is plugged into these GFCIs?

Comment: @EdBeal if this is fed from  a MWBC, OP may have no choice but to have 1 GFCI per outlet.  But in that case nothing should be attached to the LOAD terminals.  Fair chance this is a Yo Dawg situation...

Comment: @Harper I agree, I have had very limited luck on MWBC trying to find something that would work better, as the electronics are more sensitive I have had no choice other than pulling new cables in a few cases, in the past breaking out at an outlet and having the second outlet grounded and grounding conductors come from the point where they split worked well but now they tend to trip or nuncence trip with no real problems present.

Comment: Has anything changed recently anywhere in the house's electrical system?